# Android Studio libgx project throw Exception, when "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'" add in my project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, admob

I create a libgdx project in Android Studio. And I want to add admob banner in my project. So I add the this lines in build.grandle(Project: MyApplication):

```
project(":android") {

       apply plugin: "android"

       configurations { natives }

       dependencies {

           /*Some Codes...*/

           compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
           compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
      }
}
```

And then I get this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Error:Execution failed for task
':android:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

[image]

Normally, When I created a Android Studio Project and put need code line my project for admob, is works. But I dont fix the problem for Lingdx Project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this lines to your build.gradle

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have exceeded the 65k method limit.

Replace

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

With

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

And you should be fine